# Why Does My Code Return Blanks? (scraping with Scrapy)

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping

My goal is to scrape the comics in order of day of the week and save it to an excel datasheet. My source is https://comic.naver.com/webtoon/weekday.nhn.

I have had success scraping the data directly through the terminal and would like to write a proper script for the entire process, but have had not had much success.

directly scraping the data through the terminal with `response.xpath("//div[@class='list_area daily_all']/div[1]/div/h4/span/text()").extract()` will properly yield the data. The weekdays are ordered from div[1~7], and this code returns "Monday."

The following code returns a list of Monday comics.
`response.xpath("//div[@class='list_area daily_all']/div[1]/div//ul/li/a[@class='title']/text()").extract()`

However, the following code does not return the desired results.

```
def parse(self, response):
    for webtoon in response.xpath("//div[@class='list_area daily_all']/div/div"):
        yield {
            'Day': webtoon.xpath('/h4/span/text()').extract(),
            'Title': webtoon.xpath("/ul/li/a[@class='title']/text()").extract(),
        }
```

The expected result would be 7 lines of the following code, in order of day of the week
`{'Day': [day], 'Title': [title1, title2, title3]}`

However, my code is returning
`{'Day': [], 'Title': []}`

I hope this all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start your "Day" and "Title" regex with a . (dot).

When you do this, doesn't matter that you are not using `response.xpath` you are still trying to get a `h4` element at the root of the XML, not a `h4` tag after the `list_area daily_all` div.

```
webtoon.xpath('/h4/span/text()').extract()
```

The correct way to do this is adding a `.` before the `/h4`, this dot references the current position of your previous xpath selector.

```
webtoon.xpath('./h4/span/text()').extract()
```

Comment: Oh my God, I knew the answer to this but just couldn't connect the dots. Thank you so much, this was just a stepping stone in my web crawling journey and I'm ready for the next.

Comment: Actually, instead of `./` you can use `h4` directly. If there is no `/` before the element, `./` is assumed.